# How to programatically select a node in a treeList (Kendo)

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

Is there a way to select a node in  a treeList by default ?

How can I select a node in a treeList programmatically ?

Is there a method similar to findByUid as in a treeView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, there is a method called `select()`:

```
var tr = $("#treelist .k-grid-content tr:first"); // The row
$("#treelist").data("kendoTreeList").select(tr);
```

The method accepts only a `tr` element.

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EpiHa).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select a Node by default, you can do it by setting the node's `selected` property to `true` when you initialise the dataSource.  Another option would be to call the TreeView `select()` method after the TreeView completed the data loading.  (See the [dataBound](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview#events-dataBound) event for more details since the TreeView initialization may be completed before the data gets fully loaded)

For the selection, there's a [findByUid](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview#methods-findByUid) method that can be used in the TreeView.  The `findByUid` function will return the jQuery nodes matching the specified `uid`.  You can then use the results to select a node programatically by using the `select()` method:

```
var dataItem = treeview.dataSource.get(10);
var node = treeview.findByUid(dataItem.uid);
treeview.select(node);
```